# Cannot POST with React.js form

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs

I'm trying to submit a very basic form in ReactJS to my SQL database using PHP. It comes up with blank screen that says cannot POST /process-form.php

I must be doing something very basic wrong but can't figure out what it is

React Code

```
import React from 'react'

function Form() {
    return (
            <div>
                <form action="process-form.php" method="POST">
                   <label htmlFor="age">Age</label>
                   <input type="text" />
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
    )
}

export default Form
```

process-form.php code

```
<?php
$age = $_POST['age'];
//db connection
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'test';

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (age)
        VALUES (?)";

        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if ( ! mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            die(mysqli_error($conn));
        }

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $age);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            echo "Record saved";

?>
```

My app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Form from './components/basic-form';

function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/basic-form" element={<Form />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Not sure if it's relevant but I'm hosting myphpadmin on port 80 but hosting my react app on port 3000

Comment: Check the server error logs to see if there is any information there.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: It depends on the server and webserver. For linux, it's often in `/var/log/httpd` or `/var/log/apache2` or `/var/log/nginx`

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but I'm hosting myphpadmin on port 80 but hosting my react app on port 3000

Comment: phpMyAdmin has nothing to do with your code. It's just a tool that you are using.

Comment: Please remove `die(mysqli_error($conn));` from your code as not only it's incorrect, but also could be a security issue if it was written correctly

Comment: done, any suggestions on what to replace with